# Mongo: how to count several arrays in one aggregation via java's mongoTemplate

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongotemplate

I have to following Db data:

```
{user : Tom, CORRECT: {q1, q3}, WRONG : {q2, q4} },
{user : jim, CORRECT: {q1}, WRONG : {q2, q3, q4} },
{user : Tom, CORRECT: {q6}, WRONG : {7} },
```

I'd like to use aggregation to get a count of each CORRECT\WRONG per user, i.e.

```
{user : Tom, correctCount : 3, wrongCount : 3},
{user : jim, correctCount : 1, wrongCount : 3},
```

What I've tried is this:

```
    Aggregation agg = newAggregation(
            group("name").
                    addToSet(correct).as(correct).
                    addToSet(wrong).as(wrong).
                    addToSet(partial).as(partial)
    );
```

But for each user I get the full list of data (i.e. q1,q2,q3...), I can always do size() on that list - but it's inneficient. how can I get the count value instead?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One way you can go about this is to create an extra field that has the size of those arrays using the **[`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/#exp._S_size)** operator in the **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)** pipeline step and then group the documents in the **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** pipeline to get the accumulated sum as the counts on the new size field:

**Mongo shell:**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$project": {
            "user": 1,
            "correctSize": { "$size": "$CORRECT" },
            "wrongSize": { "$size": "$WRONG" }
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$user",
            "correctCount": { "$sum": "$correctSize" },
            "wrongCount": { "$sum": "$wrongSize" }
        }
    }
])
```

**Java:** use **[SpEL `andExpression`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.aggregation.examples.example5)** in the project step to use the **[`$size` expression](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-979)**

```
import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.Expressions.*; //new
...
Aggregation agg = newAggregation(
    project("user")
        .andExpression(expression("size", field("CORRECT"))).as("correctSize");
        .andExpression(expression("size", field("WRONG"))).as("wrongSize");
    group("user")
        .sum("correctSize").as("correctCount")
        .sum("wrongSize").as("wrongCount")
);
```